# Filter JQuery Datatable By Passing Parameter

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, datatables

I'm building an ASP.Net MVC 5 web application which using JQuery Datatables (1.10.4) to display tabular data within one of my Razor Views. Because the table will only ever display max 300 records, all the records are displayed at once, i.e., no Ajax/ JSon used to pull data on a per need basis.

I have used this https://datatables.net/examples/api/multi_filter_select.html to add drop down menus to some of Datatable columns to allow for filtering. This works nicely (see code below).

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {


        $('#dataTables-example').dataTable({
            "columnDefs": [
                            { "width": "1%", "targets": 0, "orderable": false },
                            { "width": "5%", "targets": 1 },
                            { "width": "10%", "targets": 2 },
                            { "width": "5%", "targets": 3 },
                            { "width": "1%", "targets": 4 },
                            { "width": "1%", "targets": 5 },
                            { "width": "1%", "targets": 6 },
                            { "width": "1%", "targets": 7, "orderable": false }
                          ]
                          ,
            initComplete: function () {
                var api = this.api();

                api.columns().indexes().flatten().each(function (i) {
                    var column = api.column(i);

                    //Only show filter for these columns
                    if (i == 1 || i == 2 || i == 3) {

                        var select = $('<select style="width: 170px;"><option value="">Select</option></select>')
                    .appendTo($(column.footer()).empty())
                    .on('change', function () {
                        var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(
                            $(this).val()
                        );

                        column
                            .search(val ? '^' + val + '$' : '', true, false)
                            .draw();
                    });

                    column.data().unique().sort().each(function (d, j) {
                        select.append('<option value="' + d + '">' + d + '</option>')
                    });

                    }

                });

            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

My problem is that when the page loads, I pass a value in the querystring `http://localhost:55437/Shift?value1=testValue`, I wish to use that querystring value (Value1) and pass it to one of the drop down filters so that the Datatable data automatically filters based on the value received from the querystring. Does this make sense?

If so, could someone please help me on how to do this?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out myself. What I needed to do was retrieve the querystring value then set the drop down value and redraw the table data. See code below, hopefully it helps someone else.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        function getParameterByName(name) {
            name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");
            var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
        results = regex.exec(location.search);
            return results === null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
        }

        var trust = getParameterByName('trust');
        //alert(trust);

        //$.fn.dataTable.ext.legacy.ajax = true;
        $('#dataTables-example').dataTable({
            "columnDefs": [
                            { "width": "1%", "targets": 0, "orderable": false },
                            { "width": "5%", "targets": 1 },
                            { "width": "10%", "targets": 2 },
                            { "width": "5%", "targets": 3 },
                            { "width": "1%", "targets": 4 },
                            { "width": "1%", "targets": 5 },
                            { "width": "1%", "targets": 6 },
                            { "width": "1%", "targets": 7, "orderable": false }
                          ]
                          ,
            initComplete: function () {
                var api = this.api();

                api.columns().indexes().flatten().each(function (i) {
                    var column = api.column(i);


                    if (i == 1 || i == 2 || i == 3) {
                        //alert("2");

                        var select = $('<select style="width: 170px;"><option value="">Select</option></select>')
                    .appendTo($(column.footer()).empty())
                    .on('change', function () {
                        var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(
                            $(this).val()
                        );

                        column
                            .search(val ? '^' + val + '$' : '', true, false)
                            .draw();
                    });

                        column.data().unique().sort().each(function (d, j) {

                            if (i == 2) {
                                //Decode ampersand
                                var decoded = d.replace(/&amp;/g, '&');

                                if (decoded == trust) {
                                    select.append('<option value="' + d + '" selected>' + d + '</option>')

                                    column
                            .search(decoded ? '^' + decoded + '$' : '', true, false)
                            .draw();

                                }
                                else {
                                    select.append('<option value="' + d + '">' + d + '</option>')
                                }

                            }
                            else {
                                select.append('<option value="' + d + '">' + d + '</option>')
                            }

                        });

                    }

                });

            }
        });

    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Might be this will helpful to solve your query if i understand your question properly. Try

```
$('#dataTables-example').fnFilter('value1');
```

after

```
$('#dataTables-example').dataTable({ your code... });
```

value1 in bracket is your get value which you have to write there in .net format.